# Feedback in Integrator Amplifier of Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

Why in analog computers for the integrator amplifier the feedback resistor is not applied? So, how to make sure (apart from resistors configuration) that circuit operates in linear phase?

Comment: What feedback resistor in what circuit? Show an example circuit.

Comment: just in any integrator amplifier of an analog computer

Comment: *just in any integrator amplifier of an analog computer* Not good enough. It is so easy: in Google search type: "integrator amplifier circuit" and press the images tab. Pick a circuit, copy-paste here. How hard is that. Realize that when you ask something, the amount of effort you put in affects how much of an answer you will get back. Better questions get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

"*Why in analog computers for the integrator amplifier the feedback resistor is not applied? So, how to make sure (apart from resistors configuration) that circuit operates in linear phase?*"

The answer is quite simple: In analog computers, the integrator is used always in a closed-loop which - for operating point stability reasons - represents a negative feedback loop for DC. Hence, the feedback resistor which realizes negative DC feedback for the "naked" integrator stage is not necessary. Tne integrator block works with a fixed stabilized DC operating point.

Comment: Also, I think, chopper amplifiers were used...

Answer (score 1):

Integrators are just part of a solution in a closed loop. If the integrator output saturates it’s gain becomes zero with just a fixed DC output error. So the design must ensure the response of the system with proportional gain and partial derivative gain ( to improve stability) must respond faster than the integrator can saturate.  Then the average input equals the reference voltage so the integrator can amplify small errors about the reference V until zero.

Normally the steady state error is reduced by then open loop DC gain divided by the feedback ratio or the net feedback gain.  The integrator is useful to amplify this steady state proportional error naturally with a slower time constant than the system and thus designed not to saturate.

In some cases a dual proportional gain can be switched (analog switch and reduce R) to improve response time but more noise  amplification then reduce when the error is small enough, the gain is reduced for low jitter and integrated error is thus is useful to optimize the small signal change vs large signal change performance.

If the system cannot meet the trade offs for fast response , 0 steady-state error and low jitter, sometimes a shunt switch may be used or a dual integrator so that one is reset ( shunt switch ) while the other is selected to initiate small error integration error correction.

The math to support these variables is often done in both time and Bode gain/ phase frequency domain but may use stability tools like Nyquist plots, Root Locus and others.

Comment: You can use Falstad’s simulator as an Analog Computer. I have, many times. Do they really still use Analog computers in univ.

Comment: There was a TUTSIM simulation program in 80s... But I was impressed with how precisely the voltages were set with ordinary potentiometers - using the compensation method with a zero indicator. When I started working at the university in '81, there was a Bulgarian version of [this computer](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/PACE-TR-10_analog_computer_-_National_Cryptologic_Museum_-_DSC07908.JPG) in the Analog Computers lab.

Comment: Looks exactly like the one we used in Winnipeg at U of M in the early ‘70’s

Comment: But with integrators and diodes one can cause chaos in a analog computer lab https://tinyurl.com/y999vfwb

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, in the integrating amplifiers of analog computers, the capacitor in the negative feedback network was charged to the required initial voltage (condition).  For this purpose, a resistor was connected in parallel to the capacitor, and a constant voltage was applied to the input of the integrator. Thus the circuit of two resistors and op-amp was acting as a DC inverting amplifier.

After the capacitor was charged, the resistor was disconnected from the capacitor... the input voltage was applied to the integrator input and the integration started.

Another interesting detail from these "analog times" (before 70s) was that op-amps were with single-ended inputs and inverting (so that negative feedback could be applied). So, op-amp functional blocks were inverting (in this way,  two voltages with opposite polarities can be subtracted in a "parallel" manner).

Later, the differential op-amp input allowed to make non-inverting circuit building blocks, in which two voltages with the same polarity could be subtracted in a series manner.

---

**EDIT** (an answer to @Hearth's comment below). With the pictures below, I have illustrated what I mean when saying that voltages can be subtracted "in a series manner" (op-amp follower - Fig. 1a) and "in a parallel manner" (op-amp inverting amplifier - Fig. 1b). In these conceptual circuits, the op-amp (hinted in light gray) is represented by a variable voltage source producing a voltage Vout.

[image: Series vs parallel voltage summing]

Fig. 1. Series (a) vs parallel (b) voltage summing

The series summer (Fig. 1a) is extremely simple. It it is "nothing" (just a loop). It sums two single-ended voltages (Vin and Vout) but the resulting voltage (dV) is floating and requires a differential op-amp input.

The parallel voltage summer (Fig. 1b) is more complex since the two voltage sources (Vin and Vout) cannot be directly connected in parallel but through resistors R1 and R2. The resulting voltage (dV = a.Vin - b.Vout) is single-ended and can be applied to an op-amp with a single-ended input.

It can be said "in parallel" since Vin + R1 and Vout + R2 can be thought of as "real voltage sources with internal resistance" (circled in yellow).

So, two voltage sources S1 and S2 are connected *in series* in the op-amp follower (Fig. 1a) and *in parallel* in the op-amp inverter (Fig. 1b).

Comment: What do you mean by "in a series manner" and "in a parallel manner"?

Comment: @Hearth, "In parallel" = applying two voltages with opposite polarities (in regard to ground) through resistors to the single op-amp input. "In series" = connecting two grounded voltage sources with the same polarity  (in regard to ground) to the op-amp inputs.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you mean. Could you draw a schematic of what you're talking about?

Comment: @Hearth, I can... but the only problem is that here it is 3 o'clock after midnight:)

Comment: @Hearth, Sorry for delay... I have added an answer to your question above and attached picture illustrating the two ways of subtracting voltages in op-amp circuits with series and parallel (shunt) negative feedback. It will be my pleasure to clarify the subject completely.

Comment: Sorry, this still isn't making sense to me. How is any of that in parallel or in series?

Comment: @Hearth, If you look at Fig. 1a, you will see two "ideal" voltage sources S1 and S2 (in yellow) connected in series and in opposite direction (polarity) through the ground. For example, travelling the loop counterclockwise, you will see +Vin- then -Vout+ so the two voltages are subtracted... and if they are equal, the result will be zero. This is the case of the op-amp follower.

Comment: Then, if you look at Fig. 1b, you will see two real voltage sources S1 and S2 (circled in yellow). We have added resistors R1/R2 in series to each of them; so we can consider the combination of an "ideal" voltage source and resistor as a "real" voltage source with internal resistance R1/R2. These two "composite" voltage sources are connected in parallel to the op-amp differential input. To implement a subtraction, they have an opposite polarity in regard to ground.

Comment: You have an unusual way of looking at circuits! To be honest it kind of grates on me sometimes just due to how different it is to how I understand things, but varied perspectives are always a good thing, I think.